# How to hide ID-s from URL in yii2

Tags: url-rewriting, yii2

I have a rule like this:

```
'home/<id:\d+>/<slug>' => 'home/view',
```

It will produce url like: `www.example.com/123/Some-title`

But I would like if ID is not shown in URL, so it becomes:

`www.example.com/Some-title`

Is this possible, and how to do it ?

P.S. I still need to do `$_GET['id']` to get article by id, I just want to hide it from URL if possible.

Comment: Just use `'home/<slug>' => 'home/view'`. Slug will now be passed as a parameter to your view action.

Comment: But I still need to use ID to get article, I can not get it from database by slug. Is this going to work then ? Im I going to have id in `$_GET` ?

Comment: If `slug ` won't allow you to retrieve a unique record then you are going to have to send the `id` instead. It's a matter of how you design things

Comment: Ah thanks, I thought that there is some way to use ID but to hide it from URL

Comment: No, you have to send it somehow! The only other way would be to have a form on the page and submit the id via a `post` request, that would do iit